# Parsing error: unexpected token, expected "," and my react app is not showing up in browser. HELP PLEASE

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App/>,
    </BrowserRouter>
    document.getElementById('root')//the word document has parsing error
);
```

I am trying to get rid of this parsing error.  In addition, my app is not showing up in my react browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the comma should be right before the `document.getElementById()` portion, like this:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>, /* this is where the comma goes */
    document.getElementById('root')//the word document has parsing error
);
```